# Relacionamento OneToOne com jpa do spring, consulta não retorna o esperado

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, rest, mariadb, spring-jpa

Estou tentando aplicar o metodo GET, mas ele não retorna os dados das outras tabelas, é um relacionamento OneToOne, quanto faço o GET ele me retorna apenas os dados de Animais, mas não o de baixas, nem desmama, eu queria que retornasse os dados dos animais e também os das outras tabelas, estou utilizando o SpringdataJPA com um banco mariadb utilizando o "findAll();" do próprio spring. ja tentei diversos tipos de metodos e mapeamentos mas não consigo o retorno esperado.

model dos animais:

```
package com.example.registrofazenda2.model;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor

@Table(name = "animal_model")
public class AnimalModel {

    public AnimalModel(int numero, char sexo, LocalDate nascimento, String marca) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.nascimento = nascimento;
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private int numero;
    private char sexo;
    private LocalDate nascimento;
    private String marca;


}
```

model de baixas

```
package com.example.registrofazenda2.model;


import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "baixas_model")
public class BaixaModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private boolean baixa;
    private LocalDate dataBaixa;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "animal_model_id")
    private AnimalModel animalModel;
}
```

model de desmama:

```
package com.example.registrofazenda2.model;


import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "desmama_model")
public class DesmamaModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private boolean desmamado;
    private LocalDate dataDesmama;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "animal_model_id")
    private AnimalModel animalModel;
}
```

parte do service

```
package com.example.registrofazenda2.service;


import com.example.registrofazenda2.model.AnimalModel;
import com.example.registrofazenda2.repository.AnimalRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AnimalService {
    private AnimalRepository animalRepository;

    public List<AnimalModel> listar() {
        return animalRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está pesquisando animais. Seu repositório está retornando animais. Não há navegabilidade (atributos) de AnimalModel para DesmamaModel nem para BaixaModel. Portanto, não haveria como a biblioteca de persistência 'trazer' para você estes dados.

Bibliotecas de persistência que implementam a JPA podem preencher apenas objetos referenciados dentro da classe que você está pesquisando. Como exemplo, se dentro de AnimalModel existisse um atributo do tipo BaixaModel:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "animalModel")
private Set<BaixaModel> baixas;
OU
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "animalModel")
private BaixaModel baixa;
```

ele poderia ser recuperado por meio de uma consulta.

Ainda, você teria que definir se deseja que a recuperação seja feita de modo guloso (EAGER) ou preguiçoso (LAZY).

Comment: Opa amigo,foi de grande ajuda obg, sou novo no spring.